# How to remove the white space in text area angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is there anyway to trim/remove initial and middle white space in text area when user enters N number of spaces.

The whitespace is also calcualted as character.

**Actual Results:**

[image]

**Expected Resutls**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
take a look to ngKeyup angular directive. 
You can register a scope function and perform your logic when the pressed key is a space or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` to trigger the event on textarea changes

```
 <textarea ng-model="myStr" ng-change="removeSpaces()" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

And in controller

```
  $scope.removeSpaces = function() {
    $scope.myStr=$scope.myStr.replace(/^ +/g,'').replace(/  +/g, ' ');
  };
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IMdLdUmMirFEICTyLWFv?p=preview)

**NOTE**

If you set `ng-trim = true`, ng-change will not trigger on entering space in textarea.

So There are two ways to do this

1. If you set `ng-trim="true"`, It will automatically trim the string.(But not on entering spaces)
2. If you set `ng-trim="false"`, You have to trim leading and ending spaces on event trigger

Comment: initially give more space and type "abc def". Issue exists.

Comment: I have tried the same as directive in your example. but it is not working.. https://plnkr.co/edit/CwRaDUqjN3apVKIMgyUN?p=preview